# I get an error message after my laptop sleeps, before login appears

Tags: ubuntu, lock-screen

I am running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on on Dell XPS 15 9500. When I shut the lid and sleep the machine, I get a black screen with error messages for a little while but eventually the lock screen and log in does appear. I'm not sure if the error messages are different every time but here is one example:

[image]

It's not a big problem; it only seems to cost me 10 seconds or so but it would be nice to know why it's happening and how I could fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ACPI errors like that are typically due to your kernel not being a great match to your hardware. Typing "Dell XPS 15 9500 Ubuntu kernel issue" shows many such results, some about suspending issues, suggesting that I'm making a good guess. The Dell XPS 15 9500 is a newer machine than Ubuntu 18.04, so this isn't too surprising. I'd suggest updating your kernel, but that's a riskier move than leaving this error alone. I suspect that the issue will disappear when you upgrade to Ubuntu 20.04.